# Angular App not showing the list from json local file

Tags: angularjs, webstorm

I have some dummy data in a mainMenu.json which will server to populate a list which will be the first template loaded by angular framework when app starts.

chrome console reporting no errors.

But I get a white "blank" page "right image" and not sure where I went wrong. Thanks

[image]

```js
//mainMenu.json
[{
  "name": "item1",
  "image": "item1_"
}, {
  "name": "item2",
  "image": "item2_"
}, {
  "name": "item3",
  "image": "item3_"
}]

//--------------------------------------------------------------------
//app.js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [
    'ngRoute',          //turn on deep linking
    'appControllers'    //js to handle the route
]);

//Configure how the partials are going to run
myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/list', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/mainMenu.html',
        controller: 'MainMenuCtrl'
    }).otherwise({      //home page
        redirectTo: '/list'
    });
}]);

//--------------------------------------------------------------------
// controlers.js
var appControllers = angular.module ('appControllers', []);

appControllers.controller ('MainMenuCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http){
    $http.get('js/mainMenu.json').success (function (data){
        
        $scope.menuItems = data;
    });
}]);
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

header > button {
    height: 1.5em;
    width: 1.5em;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    top: 0;
}

label.pageTitle {
    display: inline-block;
    width: calc(100% - 5em);
    text-align: center;
}

header {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}

main {
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    padding: 0.5em;
}


footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

footer > button {
    font-size: 1em;
    padding: 0.5em 1em;

}
input {
    font-size: 1em;
    width: 100%;
}

header, footer {
    background-color: white;
}

footer > button {
    padding: 0.5em 1em;
    width: 31.33%;
    margin: 0 1%;
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<!--index.html-->
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
    <script src="angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
</head>

<body>
<header>
    <button class="menuLeft" type="button" >&#9776;</button>
    <label class="pageTitle">Title of Page</label>
    <button class="menuRight" type="button">&#8942;</button>
</header>

<main ng-view></main>

<footer>
    <button class="menuLeft" type="button" >NO</button>
    <button class="menuLeft" type="button" >EXTRA</button>
    <button class="menuRight" type="button">YES</button>
</footer>

</body>
</html>

//--------------------------------------------------------------------
<!--mainMenu.html-->
<section>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in menuItems">
            <br/>
            <p>dummy</p>
            <h2>{{item.name}}</h2>
        </li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: any error in console ?

Comment: What is angularModule?
Probably is: ```var appControllers = angular.module('appControllers', []);```

Comment: Yes. just noticed it and fixed it but still same blank screen. Thus I will remove the update so that other "new" readers will not waste time. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an error in your code

```
var appControllers = angularModule ('appControllers', []);
```

It should be

```
var appControllers = angular.module ('appControllers', []);
```

To catch an error on `$http.get` promise do something like this :

```
$http.get(your_options).then(function(data){
}, function(err){
});
```

First function is your `success` callback and the second one is your `error` callback. More about `$http` can be found [HERE](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Comment: Do you still have errors in your browser's console or everything is working, but you have a blank page ? That `alert` is triggered ?

Comment: No console errors any more. Blank page still. I do not understand your last question

Comment: In `MainMenuController` you have this alert `alert("alosh");`. Can you see it  when you go to that page ?

Comment: Just noticed and removed it for no avail, still bank page. will fix the question as well. thx

Comment: If you just noticed it, that means it's not triggered on the page. So the request you are making doesn't succeed. Maybe the `path` for the json file is wrong. I'm going to edit my answer to show you how can you catch errors on that `http.get`

Comment: alert call placed one line before the call to $http.get is not reached.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100649/discussion-between-kosmo-and-fred-j).